# Получить информацию из файла повтора Fortnite

Tags: python, разработка-игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется файл с расширением `.replay` из Fortnite. Требуется получить из этого файла список, от самой первой смерти до последнего выжившего. Вид строки: (`никнэйм устраненного игрока`; `сколько осталось в живых на момент смерти игрока`). Там некая ерунда с кодировкой, на каком языке написан файл повтора?
ссылка на скачивание файла https://file.knok.xyz/HRawq/UnsavedReplay-2021.07.20-22.40.07.replay

Comment: изменил вопрос, надеюсь так лучше.

Comment: "Там некая ерунда с кодировкой" - простите, но телепатов нету, показывайте все - и код, и вход и выход.

Comment: там нет ерунды с кодировкой. файлы .replay это не тестовые лог-файлы. это фактически файл сценариев.

Comment: @Kromster смотри правку, прикрепил ссылку для скачки файла

Comment: Кажется, вот тут есть готовый парсер, можно попробовать начать с его изучения https://github.com/Shiqan/fortnite-replay-reader

Comment: @andreymal тэкс, что-то похожее, чуть позже изучу

Comment: @andreymal отлично, теперь не подскажите что за ошибки обновил вопрос прикрепил скрин

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему это двоичный файл. Да, местами там текст в `UTF-16`, но не везде, где-то там структуры данных, надо знать где там что лежит, как просто текст этот файл не расшифровывается:

```
import requests

url = 'https://file.knok.xyz/HRawq/UnsavedReplay-2021.07.20-22.40.07.replay'
file = requests.get(url)
file.content[:64].decode('utf-16')
```

Вывод:

```
Ტ燍拿ā﻿Несохранённый повтор
```

Т.е. сначала явно идёт какой-то бинарный заголовок, потом текст в `UTF-16`, потом ещё какие-то байты и т.д., местами `UTF-16` потом ругается, что не может расшифровать, так что это точно бинарные данные вперемешку с текстом.

Comment: скопировал ваш код в отдельный файл, выдет ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

Comment: @demid.gromiko Да вам особо толку от этого кода не будет, там надо структуру знать - в каких байтах что хранится, чтобы всё это разобрать. Мой код просто показывает, что текст в файле есть, но там не только текст. А так `requests` - довольно стандартный модуль, но если его нет, нужно поставить через `pip install requests`

Comment: у меня установлен этот модуль, но vs code все равно пишет no module named

Comment: Ну, вам нужно разбираться, сколько у вас на компьютере питонов установлено, какие виртуальные окружения и т.д.